# Omitting price property for sold products?

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets, price

I'm adding Schema.org (using Microdata) to a product page. My client wants the price omitted for sold products - she doesn't want anyone to be able to see the price of sold products.

However this was showing up as an error in the Microdata for 'price': [check page in Google SDTT](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.modernprints.co.uk%2Fproducts%2Fpeter-blake-tweedledum-from-through-the-looking-glass)

Obviously the average user will still not be able to see the price, but it's used by Google Shopping so might show up.

Should I just put a price of 0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s perfectly fine to have an `Offer` without a `price`.

If Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool complains, it does not necessarily mean that you have an error in your Microdata or Schema.org.  In your case Google’s error message just means:

*If you don’t provide a price, we won’t be able to show our [Products rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/products) for your product.*

The point of this rich result is showing their users data about your product, including its price. If you don’t have a price, there is no point for Google to display it. **Don’t provide a fake price (like `0`),** just omit the `price` property. Otherwise you convey that your product has a price (in case of `0`, that the product is gratis), which would be misleading.