# Products with no set price in Google Rich Cards?

Tags: data-structures, google-search, schema.org, json-ld

I'm currently implementing Rich Card Snippets for the Services we provide on our site, so that there's a chance that the products may show higher on results thanks to these rich cards but after a look around there's no option that suits the packages which require a bespoke solution for each instance.

> Due to the complexity of registering RTM’s we do not have set costs or
>   set packages.  Please contact us directly to discuss your
>   requirements, where we will be able to give you an estimate and time
>   scale.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Limited Liability Partnership",
  "alternateName":"LLP",
  "image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000561746118/2bf53fff069b75bfa53e33bd79cd3230.png",
  "description": "RTM companies were introduced under the Commonhold and Lease Reform Act 2002. They are private companies Limited by Guarantee, enabling leaseholders in blocks of apartments to take over the management of their building. There are constitutional rules which apply to this type of company. Due to the complexity of registering RTM’s we do not have set costs or set packages. ",
  "brand": {
    "@type": "Service",
    "name": "Company Formation"
  },
  "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "priceCurrency": "GB",
    "price": "0",
    "itemOffered": "Service",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "seller": {
      "@type": "LocalBusiness",
      "name": "Murphy Thompson Moore LLP"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

What's my best option here;

- Don't include the price field? (and have Google Search Console complain of errors. And also potentially confuse users.)
- Put Price as Zero? (which causes Structured Data to put price as free, which may appear misleading.)
- Don't include the products which require bespoke solutions at all?
- Some other option which I'm not aware of?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Omitting price property for sold products?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788598/omitting-price-property-for-sold-products)

Comment: There's some similarities,  but I'd say it's different enough,  as I've mentioned,  I'm already aware of that,  it's more of a question of what is the best solution for better results from Google.

Comment: But doesn’t my answer there already answer it? You should not say that the price is 0 (because it’s not true), so the only option is to omit price. That means that you won’t get the Google search result feature for products, because it requires a price.